# With FFmpeg, how do I normalize AC3 to stereo WAV file?

Tags: ffmpeg, ac3

I'm converting 5.1 AC3 file to stereo WAV with FFmpeg:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "D:\Project\AC3.ac3" -ac 2 "D:\Project\WAV.wav"
```

1. How do I normalize the file?
2. Is there a way to know how much I can increase the volume before clipping occurs?
3. How do I increase the volume?

I'm using Windows 7 x64 with the latest FFmpeg build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalizing with FFmpeg is a two-step process. First, you need to use the `volumedetect` filter which will tell you exactly how much dB you're allowed to crank up :

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "D:\Project\AC3.ac3" -ac 2 -af volumedetect -y NUL
```

This will show you the maximum volume of the stereo (downmixed) track along with additional information :

```
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x20fb060] n_samples: 155043840
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x20fb060] mean_volume: -26.5 dB
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x20fb060] max_volume: -3.2 dB
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x20fb060] histogram_3db: 23
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x20fb060] histogram_4db: 87
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x20fb060] histogram_5db: 672
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x20fb060] histogram_6db: 2157
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x20fb060] histogram_7db: 5848
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x20fb060] histogram_8db: 15951
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x20fb060] histogram_9db: 36078
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x20fb060] histogram_10db: 73237
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x20fb060] histogram_11db: 138626
```

And then you can normalize your track :

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "D:\Project\AC3.ac3" -ac 2 -af volume=3.2dB "D:\Project\WAV.wav"
```